# Chrome extension for opening files directly?

Tags: chrome, download-manager

I have set Chrome to ask me where I would like to save each download. I don't like all my downloads being saved automatically in my Downloads folder.

Now, what I *would* like is if each time I download a file, I get the option to just "open" it, rather than put it somewhere in the filesystem on my computer. I realize the file would still be saved somewhere, but this could just be a temporary file. I wouldn't need to set a folder for it to be saved in, or worry about cluttering up my filesystem with files I'm only gonna look at once.

Is there any way to achieve this? I'm thinking of an extension, so platform should be irrelevant, but in case it's needed, I'm on OS X 10.10.1.

Comment: Most browsers used to prompt users for exactly this: <Save> or <Open> on download. The reason Chrome (and indeed all the major browsers) got away from this is it creates security issues that are not easily mitigated. Saving somewhere to disk and letting the host operating system take over management (and potential opening/running) of the file is the only way to safely handle this (and even then it's dangerous). You probably shouldn't do this, and even if you do knowing the risks, such a thing probably shouldn't be in a distributed extension.

Comment: @Caleb Is this the case even for non-executables?

Comment: Yes it does. The issues there are a little different and vary by OS and enabled security features, but in very broad strokes this applies across the board.

Comment: @Caleb That's too bad. I'm curious as to why, but that's a question for Security SE. It's probably already been asked there. I'll get back to this later. Thanks for the info.

Comment: What would be better is if there was a way (extension, program, etc.) to open non-.exe files in-browser without downloading. Instead of downloading it to your computer, it could automatically add it to your Google Drive (or any other online space that can temporarily hold a file) with a do-not-sync flag, and delete it when you close the file.

Comment: @MichelfrancisBustillos Yeah that would be great. There are ways to do it, but they're a bit tricky. There are Chrome extensions that "add item to Google Drive." If you sync your Google Drive to your local drive, you could use a Drive client that allows for excluding certain folders. Or you could set up the extension to work with a second Google account which is not synced locally.

Comment: @Fiksdal You would also need a way to have the file open in-browser (most will be able to use Google Drive's preview function, but not all) automatically. If I had the time, I'd definitely create something like this.

Comment: @MichelfrancisBustillos Yeah, it should be doable :)

Comment: This might not help very much, but if you're talking about PDFs, enabling `Chrome PDF Viewer` in `chrome://plugins` will make all PDFs 'open' without saving. but I don't know about other types of files, so +1 :)